# How to do that image was a little outside the cardView

Tags: java, android, xaml

I try to do, that ImageView was a little outside of cardView. I assume this will work with FrameView. But a little later I realized that I needed a view that would go on top of CardView, because if I try to place a picture inside cardview, then no matter how I shift it, CardView will stretch.

Target design

[image]

Current design

[image]

P.S: I can implement the rest of the parts myself, I can't figure out how to make the same design of the picture so that it falls out of their CardView a little.

Current xaml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    style="@style/BottomCornerRadiusCard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#0096ff">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Фамилия Имя Отчество"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="24dp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="#0096ff"
                android:src="@drawable/baseline_exit_to_app_32"
                android:layout_marginStart="110dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ваш рейтинг: N"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="24dp"/>

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="250dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="100dp">

                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="250dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="95dp"
                        android:layout_height="95dp"
                        android:background="#0096ff"
                        android:src="@drawable/micro_scooter" />

                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a ConstraintLayout instead of a Linear or Relative.

And you haves to think the view as the "parent" of the components that haves inside.

So, if you want a image outside of a cardView, for example, you haves to put it out of the card...

That is the reason I recommend you to use a Constraint, this type of layout will let you order your views easily...

Good Luck! :D